# How to set constants from file once for app working session

Tags: file, javafx, constants

I have javafx application. What i want to do:
When application starts, it reads some file with userConstants (email data, phone data etc) and save it somewhere and uses those constants all time during application working session. So where do i need to store this data? Some special class, or enum? I don't want to read this file every time, when other classes needs those constants.

I hope you understand my question )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class ConstantsClassName{
    public static final  String MAXARRAYSIZE;
    static{
        // read your file and store the data in;
        MAXARRAYSIZE = valueRetrievedFromFile;
    }
}
```

Solution found! From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724713/read-in-file-for-constants-java)